# Сделать обработку второго клика по блоку

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Люди такая  проблему у меня есть блок по которому при нажатии появляется другой блок. Нужно сделать что бы при повторном нажатии появляющийся блок исчезал.

```js
function info() {
    r = document.getElementById('mobile_info');
    d = document.getElementById('flag');
    if(r.style.display != 'block')
        r.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#block_flag{
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FAF0E6;      
}

#mobile_info{
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 170px;
        background-color: #FAF0E6;
        z-index: 9998;
        padding-top: 70px;
        animation: info 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    @keyframes info {
      0% {transform: translateY(-170px);}
      100% {transform: translateY(0);}
      
    }
    
    #flag{
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        background-color: #27a327;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        right: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index:9999;
    }
    
    #flag:before{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        top: 100%;
        border-left: 20px solid #27a327;
        border-right: 20px solid #27a327;
        border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    }
    
    #flag:after {
        content: '•••';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
        font-size: 26px; 
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        color: white;
    }
    
    #flag:hover::after{
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: red;
    }
    
    #flag:active::after{
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: red;
    }
  
  .block_info{
        position: relative;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 5px ridge Crimson;
        border-radius: 60px;
    }
    
    .in_block_info{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%);
        height: 170px;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 350px;
        
    }
    
    .time_work{
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
    
    #logo_work{
        height: 45px;
        width: 45px;
        background-image: url(images/work.png);
        margin-top: 7px;
    }

    #work{
        height: 60px;
        color: black;
    }

    .number1{
        margin-top: 0.3em;
        margin-left: 1em;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .number2{
        margin-top: 0.1em;
        margin-left: 1em;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .telephone{
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }

    #logo_phone{
        height: 45px;
        width: 45px;
        background-image: url(images/phone.png);
        margin-top: 7px;
    }

    #phone{
        height: 60px;
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<div id="block_flag">
        <div onclick="info()" id="flag"></div>
        <div id="mobile_info">
            <div class="block_info">
                <div class="in_block_info">
                    <div class="telephone">
                        <div id="logo_phone"></div>
                        <div id="phone">
                            <div class="number1">Позвоните нам</div>
                            <div class="number2">+7-000-000-00-00</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="time_work">
                        <div id="logo_work"></div>
                        <div id="work">
                            <div class="number1">8:00 до 24:00</div>
                            <div class="number2">C Понедельника по Пятницу</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: element.classList.toogle(newClass)

Comment: @MaximLensky  Чет не вкурил если можно поясните по подробней

Comment: у вас же есть кнопка при нажатии на которую вы показываете блок ? так вот пишите так - кнопка.onclick = function (){ нужныйБлок.classList.toggle(view")} в css должно быть написано правило которое покажет блок, к примеру .view{display: block} - если не ясно напишите мне об этом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function info() {
    r = document.getElementById('mobile_info');
    d = document.getElementById('flag');
    if(r.style.display != 'block'){r.style.display = 'block'}
    else{r.style.display = 'none'}

}
```

```css
#block_flag{
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FAF0E6;      
}

#mobile_info{
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 170px;
        background-color: #FAF0E6;
        z-index: 9998;
        padding-top: 70px;
        animation: info 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    @keyframes info {
      0% {transform: translateY(-170px);}
      100% {transform: translateY(0);}
      
    }
    
    #flag{
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        background-color: #27a327;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        right: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index:9999;
    }
    
    #flag:before{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        top: 100%;
        border-left: 20px solid #27a327;
        border-right: 20px solid #27a327;
        border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    }
    
    #flag:after {
        content: '•••';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
        font-size: 26px; 
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        color: white;
    }
    
    #flag:hover::after{
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: red;
    }
    
    #flag:active::after{
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: red;
    }
  
  .block_info{
        position: relative;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 5px ridge Crimson;
        border-radius: 60px;
    }
    
    .in_block_info{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%);
        height: 170px;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 350px;
        
    }
    
    .time_work{
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
    
    #logo_work{
        height: 45px;
        width: 45px;
        background-image: url(images/work.png);
        margin-top: 7px;
    }

    #work{
        height: 60px;
        color: black;
    }

    .number1{
        margin-top: 0.3em;
        margin-left: 1em;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .number2{
        margin-top: 0.1em;
        margin-left: 1em;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .telephone{
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }

    #logo_phone{
        height: 45px;
        width: 45px;
        background-image: url(images/phone.png);
        margin-top: 7px;
    }

    #phone{
        height: 60px;
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<div id="block_flag">
        <div onclick="info()" id="flag"></div>
        <div id="mobile_info">
            <div class="block_info">
                <div class="in_block_info">
                    <div class="telephone">
                        <div id="logo_phone"></div>
                        <div id="phone">
                            <div class="number1">Позвоните нам</div>
                            <div class="number2">+7-000-000-00-00</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="time_work">
                        <div id="logo_work"></div>
                        <div id="work">
                            <div class="number1">8:00 до 24:00</div>
                            <div class="number2">C Понедельника по Пятницу</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Еще можно вот так:

```
function info() {
    const r = document.getElementById('mobile_info');
    r.classList.toggle('show')
}
```

`.show{display:block!important}`

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/yLbLrwM - вот так - смотри

Comment: что бы не было important используй совсем другое - смотри опять мой codepen

Comment: @MaximLensky Благодарю попробую ваш вариант в первую очередь.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в html внести изменения. Добавить класс для понижения CSS-специфичности:

```
    <div id="mobile_info" class='mobile_info'>
```

Далее, в CSS заменить # на . И добавить класс d-block

```
    .mobile_info{
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 170px;
        background-color: #FAF0E6;
        z-index: 9998;
        padding-top: 70px;
        animation: info 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .d-block{
        display: block;
    }
```

И в Javascript:

```
    function info() {
        r = document.getElementById('mobile_info');
        d = document.getElementById('flag');
        r.classList.toggle('d-block');
    }
```

Данный метод добавляет класс, если он отсутствует, и удаляет, если он имеется.